# Java: method which receives pointer to other method (lambda)

Tags: java, c++, methods, reference, lambda

Recently I've been trying to familiarize myself with the usage of lambdas in Java 8.
I've found that I can pass to some method a pointer to another method, like this:

```
List<Integer> numbers = asList(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9);
forEach(System.out::println, numbers);
```

This is clear for me.
However, how can I create a method which expects such pointer?
Should it work like in eg. C++? Or maybe my expectations are too big?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Methods which expect method references use functional interfaces as their agruments.

Takes for example `numbers.forEach(System.out::println);`

[forEach](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Iterable.html#forEach-java.util.function.Consumer-) is defined as:

```
void forEach(Consumer<? super T> action)
```

It means it expects a method reference or lambda expression that conform to the single method of the [Consumer](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Consumer.html) functional interface.

`Consumer<T>` has a single method - [void accept(T t)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Consumer.html#accept-T-).
That means it expects a method that requires a single parameter and has no return value.
`System.out::println` fits this requirement.

Comment: A short list of the most common functional interfaces would be awesome.

Answer (score 2):

> I can pass to some method, pointer to another method

No. That is not what you are doing. With the method reference syntax, you're passing an instance of a class that implements some target functional interface with the body of the method referenced.

> But how to create method which expects such pointer?

You create a method where the parameter is of an appropriate functional interface type.

Answer (score 0):

The argument type should be a functional interface ([§9.8](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-9.html#jls-9.8)):

> In addition to the usual process of creating an interface instance by declaring and instantiating a class ([§15.9](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.9)), instances of functional interfaces can be created with method reference expressions and lambda expressions ([§15.13](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.13), [§15.27](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.27)).